# Target list items in primary ul but not nested ul

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to add css styles to parent list.

I have one parent `ul` and children. I want to apply color to **fruits**, **vegetables** and **flowers** but not **Apple**, **Banana**, **Orange**.

I want to do this using a CSS selector.

```css
ul:root>li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Fruits
    <ul>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
      <li>Orange</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Vegetables</li>
  <li>Flowers</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the exact style that you will be applying to these elements? `color` is an inherited property and so once you assign it to the outer `li`, the `ul` and `li` inside it will inherit the color. You'd have to over-ride it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add a class to the parent `ul` and then use the direct descendant selector to target only those `li` items.

This is definitely going to change the colors for **Apple** or **Orange** but you can then reset the color on the sub `ul` items.

Here's your updated demo.

```css
.parent-list > li {
  color: red;
}
.parent-list > li ul {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent-list">
  <li>Fruits
    <ul>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
      <li>Orange</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Vegetables</li>
  <li>Flowers</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this...

```html
<ul>
  <li>Fruits
    <ul>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
      <li>Orange</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Vegetables</li>
  <li>Flowers</li>
</ul>
       

<style>
ul li{
  color: red;
}
ul li li{
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul > li {                /* select list items that are children of a ul */
  color: red;
}

ul ul li {               /* select list items that are descendants of a ul, itself... */
  color: black;          /* ...a descendant of another ul */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Fruits
    <ul>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
      <li>Orange</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Vegetables</li>
  <li>Flowers</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<style>
ul  li {
  color: red;
}

ul ul li {
  color: black;
}
</ul>

</style>


<ul>
  <li>Fruits
    <ul>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
      <li>Orange</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Vegetables</li>
  <li>Flowers</li>
```